# Java - ImageIO throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, embedded-resource, javax.imageio, illegalargumentexception

Hello Java Developers,

So I have recently encountered this problem. Here's and SSCCE:

```
public class SampleClass extends JPanel{

    private Image img;
    private final String IMG_DIRECTORY = ("/res/BG.png");

    public SampleClass(){

        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(IMG_DIRECTORY));
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

This line throws the exception

```
img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(IMG_DIRECTORY));
```

Here's the StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.forte.project.chatservice.uicomponent.FrameBackground.<init>(FrameBackground.java:27)
    at com.forte.project.chatservice.ui.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:27)
    at com.forte.project.chatservice.ChatService.main(ChatService.java:18)
```

I have done the following:
- Google. 
- Updated my Java 
- .getResourceAsStream(IMG_DIRECTORY); 
- this.getClass().getResource(IMG_DIRECTORY)); 
- MainClass.class.getClass().getResource(IMG_DIRECTORY);

Comment: print `getClass().getResource(IMG_DIRECTORY)` what does it produces?

Comment: can u point out line 27 nd 18?

Comment: it is not SSCCE, it is not compileable.

Comment: @sansix Line 27 is: img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(IMG_DIRECTORY)); and 18 @ MainClass is: SampleClass sample= new SampleClass();

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Instatiate the class in you Main class.

Comment: Try removing the preceding / from IMG_DIRECTORY ie IMG_DIRECTORY = "res/BG.png";. Based on its current value, it may be trying to access a resource in the base directory.

Comment: 1) Edit the output from `jar -tvf the.jar` into the question. 2) An  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) requires a `main(String[])` to be an SSCCE (unless it is an applet, servlet etc.). 3) `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);` 4) But see [`ImageViewer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512826/418556).  Image(s) centered in a scroll pane.

Comment: Try copy pasting your `BG.png` in your package directly,and then use `IMG_DIRECTORY = ("BG.png")` does it still gives you an NP Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing `res` folder to `src` folder fixed the problem.