# Adding an image obtained from webcam to an existing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, opencv, webcam, javacv

I was trying to add an image I capture from a webcam to an existing JPanel when a button is clicked, but the JPanel never displays the image. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
private void captureButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    BufferedImage img1;
    JLabel label;
    final OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);

    try {
        grabber.start();
        IplImage img = grabber.grab();
        if (img != null) {

            img1 = img.getBufferedImage();
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img1);
            label = new JLabel(icon);
            //photo is the name of the JPanel
            photo.add(label);
            photo.setVisible(true);
            grabber.stop();
            System.out.println("done");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

EDIT: This is the whole class. (Trimmed it to make it easier to read)

```
package honoursproject;

    import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
    import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class AddPerson extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form AddPerson */
public AddPerson() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    nameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    surnameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    photo = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    captureButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    saveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    cancelButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    photo.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0,       0)));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void captureButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    BufferedImage img1;
    JLabel label;
    final OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    try {
        grabber.start();
        IplImage img = grabber.grab();

        if (img != null) {

       img1 = img.getBufferedImage();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img1);
        label = new JLabel(icon);
        //photo is the name of the JPanel
        photo.add(label);
        photo.setVisible(true);
        grabber.stop();
        System.out.println("done");


            grabber.stop();
            System.out.println("done");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}                                             



public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new AddPerson().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton cancelButton;
private javax.swing.JButton captureButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JTextField nameField;
private javax.swing.JPanel photo;
private javax.swing.JButton saveButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField surnameField;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Any Exceptions? Have you already printed the icon etc. to see what their value is?

Comment: no exceptions, the program completes without errors and the "done" is printed out.

Comment: Are you using a layout manager? Do you need to add more then one image at a time?

Comment: I am using a layout manager but no, i only need one image to be added at the click of a button.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  To do that, factor out all the webcam complications and simply generate an image in code using `new BufferedImage(40,40,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)`.  See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512826/418556) of an SSCCE that shows images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a JLabel instead of a JFrame or a JPanel and it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you're adding a new component to your `photo` `JPanel` you will need to update & paint the container:

```
photo.revalidate();
photo.repaint();
```

Alternatively, the `JLabel` could also be added at startup, allowing you to call [setIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) to update the image.

**Update:**

You don't appear to *add* your `JPanel` `photo` to your `JFrame` anywhere:

```
add(photo);
```

---

Don't create another `JFrame` to display your image. Add it to your `JPanel` using the original `JFrame`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice).

Comment: Did you call `revalidate`?

Comment: @davy307 Its possible that the image contains no data _or_ that the `JPanel` `photo` has no size. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @mKorbel, I have also tried the label.setIcon and it doesnt work, besides doesnt label = new JLabel(icon) do the same?

Comment: @Reimeus, the image does contain data, this works perfectly when i use a JFrame, but because of the kind of GUI im trying to create i need the image in a JPanel which is embedded in a JFrame.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the layout manager, can't help without seeing the frame code.

Comment: where can i post the code for it so that you can see it? Im new to asking a question ^^

Comment: If you don't have _too much_ code, you can click on the _edit_ link and insert more code.

Comment: Ok, I added pretty much the whole of the class, hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, that JFrame that you see created was just used to test that the image was actually there, I don't actually use that at all. I have already tried an InternalJFrame and it still doesnt display anything.  However, the pooint of this is not to use a Frame but a Panel, as my goal is to make it look like the photo from an ID.

Comment: don't to recreate the JComponents on runtime, change only its value (Icon)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `setIcon`:

```
label.setIcon(icon);
```