# Refreshing my JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I want to display an image on a application and when I want to open another one, I want that the new one overwrite the old.

I've looking everywhere to find a solution like use invalidate(), repaint(), etc.. but still not working and I can't figured out why the windows doesn't refresh, can someone help me?

Here the code :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
    if (e.getActionCommand().contains("Open"))
    {
        filename_ = new String();
        filename_ = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("File to open ?");
        ImagePanel test = new ImagePanel(new File(filename_));

        test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(test.getWidth(), test.getHeight()));
        test.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(test.getWidth(), test.getHeight()));
        test.repaint();
        JScrollPane tmp = new JScrollPane();
        tmp.getViewport().add(test);

        tmp.getViewport().repaint();
        mainPanel_.add(tmp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel_.repaint();
        curim_ = test;
        test.memento_ = new Memento(test);
        test.caretaker_.add(test.memento_);
        curim_ = test;


        curmodindex_ = curim_.caretaker_.getIndex();
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel_);
        System.out.println(curmodindex_);
        if (curmodindex_ != 0)
        {
            button1.setEnabled(true);
            button2.setEnabled(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please show your Graphics implementation.

Comment: You mean the Jpanel that i use for my images ?

Comment: Start from this [working implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512826/418556).  Try & adapt it to your needs.  If you cannot, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Comment: [`ImageApp`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) is a complete example.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create new components. Just update the data of existing components. Maybe something like:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( imagePanel );
```

Or even easier just use a JLabel to display your image. Then when the image changes you can use:

```
label.setIcon( new ImageIcon(...) );
```

Without a proper SSCCE its hard to guess what you are doing wrong. For example I see:

```
tmp.getViewport().add(test);
...
test.memento_ = new Memento(test);
```

Without knowing what your code does it looks like you are trying to add the same component to two different components which is not allowed.

Comment: In fact, I have a ImagePanel class which extends JPanel, my image are in this JPanel, then I put my JPanel in a ScrollPanel to get scroll bars, then i put my ScollPanel in a MainPanel that is in my JFrame.

Comment: I understand what you are doing. There is no need to create the custom panel for your image. You can just use a JLabel.