# Periodically change JLabel icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I have to change the the icon of a jLabel every 2 seconds. I use a Timer and a Timer task to do this, but it only shows the first image. Here is the code:

```
    ImageIcon[] icons = {new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("orange.jpg")), new     
    ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("cosmote.jpg")), new 
    ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("vodafone.jpg"))};
    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
    int indexIcon;
```

And then in the JFrame constructor:

```
    initComponents();
    open(fisierAgenda);
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            indexIcon=(indexIcon++)%3;
            jLabel.setIcon(icons[indexIcon]);
            jLabel.setText(""+indexIcon);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 2000);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Implement a **Swing** `Timer` for repeating tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  See also this [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512826/418556).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Swing is Single Threaded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and all events must be done on EDT
- output from `util.Timer` never will be notifyed `Event Dispatch Thread`, without any changes to the already visible `Swing GUI`
- use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), then output will be always done on EDT

Answer (score -1):

You should use a thread for this. At least, that's what I would use.

Comment: Not the down-voter, but all edits and updates to Swing GUIs should be on the EDT.

Comment: Not the down-voter either but: 1) All updates should be done on the EDT (so the simplest thing is to use a Swing Timer) 2) Since Java 1.5, you are better off using the `Executors` framework rather than create `Thread`'s manually. 3) If needed, you can combine `Executors` and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`