# Changing only one Panel in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have one JFrame with two Buttons in East and West,Label in North,Label and TextField in South. and one Image in the Center. I want to call another Image after 30 seconds in the center. But every time I call the 2nd image the components in North,South,East and West are disappearing.

This is my code.
//The Components in JFrame.

```
    firstPicblur = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    pictureblur01 = new ImageIcon("C:\\java pics\\papsi2.jpg");
    pictureblurA = new JLabel(pictureblur01);

    firstPicblur.add(pictureblurA,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //FirstPicture blurred B
    firstPicblurB = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    pictureblur02 = new ImageIcon("C:\\java pics\\papsi1.jpg");
    pictureblurB = new JLabel(pictureblur02);

    firstPicblurB.add(pictureblurB,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Next0Prev buttons
    Next0Prev = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    Next = new JButton("NEXT");
    Prev = new JButton("PREV");

    //Next0Prev labels is constant at SOUTH
    firstPicblurA = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    clueNo1 = new JLabel("Picture Number 01");
    TypeHere = new JTextField("Guess Who");

    firstPicblurA.add(TypeHere, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    firstPicblurA.add(clueNo1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    Next0Prev.add(firstPicblur,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Next0Prev.add(Next,BorderLayout.EAST);
    Next0Prev.add(Prev,BorderLayout.WEST);
    Next0Prev.add(firstPicblurA,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

//other components

and this is the actionEvent

```
        if(e.getSource() == continueButton){
        add(Next0Prev);
        Next0Prev.setVisible(true);
        Next0Prev.repaint();
        Next0Prev.revalidate();
        loadingEffectBtn.setVisible(false);
        Timer ta = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                         add(firstPicblurB);
                         firstPicblurB.setVisible(true);
                         Next0Prev.setVisible(true);
                        }
                        });
                        ta.start();
                        ta.setRepeats(true);
    }
```

but when i do this. The 2nd picture is appearing in center but the N,E,W,S components are disappearing.

Comment: Isn't all the functionality being added to `Next0Prev`, which I assume is being added to your main window.  But you're also adding `firstPicblurB` to the frame...?

Comment: Why don't you just have one picture label and change the picture, instead of having two seperate picture label?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).  See also [`ImageViewer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512826/418556) for a working example.

Comment: Yes,and that firstPicblurB is the 2nd picture. but i dont know if im doing it right.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes I will.

Comment: @peeskillet can you give me an example?

Comment: @java - Newbie. in your `actionPerofomed` just `firstPictureBlur.setIcon(...)`.

Comment: @Java-Newbie You already have an example, you're using it, simply change the label's icon

Comment: I'd declare an `Icon` array with your images. Then in your `actionPerformed` put an if statement to determine which picture is displayed, and alternate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hard to tell, but what appears to be happening is...

You're creating `Next0Prev` and adding all your components to it...

```
Next0Prev = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

//....

Next0Prev.add(firstPicblur,BorderLayout.CENTER);
Next0Prev.add(Next,BorderLayout.EAST);
Next0Prev.add(Prev,BorderLayout.WEST);
Next0Prev.add(firstPicblurA,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Which I assume you are adding to the frame...

Then in your `Timer`'s `actionPerformed`, you're adding `firstPicblurB` to the main container...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    add(firstPicblurB);
    firstPicblurB.setVisible(true);
    Next0Prev.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now, assuming that the main container is either a `JFrame` or is using a `BorderLayout`, this will effectively hide `Next0Prev` as `BorderLayout` can only have a single component in any of it's 5 positions.

Instead, you should be adding `firstPicblurB` to `Next0Prev`...

A simpler solution would be (as has already being pointed out) to use a single `JLabel` and simple change it's `icon`

I would also highly recommend that you take the time to read through and apply [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: So i will create one JLabel and that JLabel will compose two images?

Comment: Is that what you want?  Or do you want to display one at a time?

Comment: i want to display one at a time in the center of the Jframe.

Comment: Good, because `JLabel` only supports a single `Icon` at a time

Comment: so how can i call another image after 10 seconds in the center of the frame without removing the N,E,W,S components? i want to do this to save some time and effort.

Comment: Use a `javax.swing.Timer`.  When it's `actionPerformed` method is called, simply use call `pictureblurB.setIcon` with the new image icon.